# what's the meaning of "stretch before working out"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does that mean?

> "How often do you stretch before working out?"

Comment: Short answer: "working out" is an idiom for "exercising".

Comment: Extremely relevant: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23501/i-stretch-after-waking-up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Stretch before working out* is not an idiom. It simply means *stretch before you work out*. (After *before* you can use Verb<sub>ing</sub> and leave the doer of that verb to be inferred)

#### So, what does *stretch* here mean?

[image: A Girl Stretching]

This girl is *stretching*. ([Image source](http://www.cappinophysio.ca/is-stretching-really-necessary/))

The OALD gives [the definition of *stretch* in this sense as follows](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/stretch_1):

> 4 [intransitive, transitive] to put your arms or legs out straight and contract your muscles

#### What does *work out* mean?

[image: A Woman Working Out]

This woman is *working out*, which means she is doing a physical exercise ([Image source](http://7minutesworkouts.com/)), just [as the OALD says under *work out*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/work_1):

> 1 to train the body by physical exercise

---

Therefore, the question "How often do you stretch before working out?" basically means the same as "How often do you stretch before you exercise?" It is asking for the frequency you *stretch* (the first picture) before you *work out* (the second picture).

Comment: Picture dictionary is the best